# Stripe PaymentSource not expanding after upgrading to newest version of Java library

Tags: java, gradle, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get the payment methods attached to a given Customer. I recently upgraded to version 2020.19.0 of the [Stripe Java library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/releases) and I'm following [the example](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list) they've put forward.

The problem is that the Java library doesn't seem to recognize that the PaymentSource object has any parameters:

```
Map<String, Object> params = Maps.newHashMap();
params.put("object", "card");
params.put("limit", 100);

// Get the credit cards
List<PaymentSource> cards =
  customer.getSources().list(params).getData();

for (PaymentSource c : cards) {
  c.getObject();    // not recognized in IDE
}
```

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stripe-java is pinned to a specific API version. When you upgrade to a new major version in the library it usually contains breaking changes and/or an upgrade to the most recent API version. This is what happened in 20.0.0 as documented [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2000---2020-08-31) where the library was pinned to [2020-08-27](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2020-08-27).

That new API version has a lot of changes including some cleanup on the `Customer` resource. Stripe stopped returning sub-lists by default: `subscription`, `tax_ids` and `sources` are not returned unless you explicitly expand those sub-lists directly. This allows the API to be faster in most cases and to selectively select the sub-lists you need in specific parts of your code.

In Java, this means that you need to expand the `sources` collection if you want to be able to create/attach a new card. This is also documented in the API reference [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list?lang=java) and the code looks like this:

```
List<String> expandList = new ArrayList<>();
expandList.add("sources");

Map<String, Object> retrieveParams = new HashMap<>();
retrieveParams.put("expand", expandList);

Customer customer = Customer.retrieve(
  "cus_IEB3RFCf76Fais",
  retrieveParams,
  null
);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("object", "card");
params.put("limit", 3);

PaymentSourceCollection cards = customer.getSources().list(params);
```